# How to clear adapter of all listView in Different TabHost from one Tab Host in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a tabhost with three tabs. Each is an activity. In each activity there is a listview which contain same values . If a delete one item or any modification from listitem in Tab 1 , then i want to refill values of listview in Tab 2 & Tab 3.

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail or some sample code of what you have? What kind of data are you using to store the lists? Is it stored in a database, is it behind a ContentProvider? Are you using an adapter to fill the lists? These things will effect the answer.

Comment: I have values in database And filled listview with custom adapter .

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your lists from cursors, I believe you should be able to simply requery the cursors using cursor.requery().

Of course, that's assuming that you are *not* using separate activities for each tab...